# How to import IBActions from other .h file?

Tags: iphone, xcode, ipad

I have many view controllers on my iOS app and in most of them I need the exact same IBAction.

So instead of writing the same code in all view controllers, is it possible to create a separated .h file with the IBActions and then import on the viewcontroller.h?

I tried that creating a Actions.h file and importing it with the command "#import Actions.h" on the ViewController.h file, but when I go to the Interface Builder the actions doesn't show up. Is there any way to do this???

Comment: Question is good..As per my information you have to deal with Yellow cube "Object" in Object Library(i.e. where you find all buttons,labels,webviews etc)..Thats what I have heard from my senior but haven't tried it yet.

Comment: I looks like the best way, because you can access IBAction and IBOutlets from others .h files, but so far I have not been able to make it work. Until then creating a superclass is the only way I made it work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Define the method in the superclass:

```
@interface MyActionViewController: UIViewController
{
}

- (IBAction)theAction:(id)sender;

@end
```

Subclass your view controllers from it:

```
@interface FirstViewController: MyActionViewController
{
}

@end
```

Answer (score 1):

Not import, you need to inherit. Create a viewController with that IBAction and inherit that in every viewControllers that you would like to use.

Answer (score 1):

You can actually do it all in Interface Builder as well.  You can do it with the option to add an "Object" to your nib file.  In the palette with all of the interface objects, there is one with an orange-colored cube labelled "Object".

Put that one on the root-level of your view hierarchy.

Change the custom class to the name of your class (sounds like it is "Actions").  Once you have changed the name from Object to the name of the class, Interface Builder will let you access any of the IBAction on that class.

Connect the button to this custom class's IBAction.

You can do the same thing for any of the other nib files which need to use this button code, and it saves you from having to subclass.

Comment: Used like you described , function gets called but the coding was not showing any effect..

Comment: I am not sure what that means exactly...you are saying that the IBAction is successful called?  Or it is not successfully called?

Comment: This method looks great, I link the action on the ViewController, everything ok. But when I run on the simulator the app crashes everytime I click on the button connected to the IBAction.

Comment: I created the Object, changed the class to "Actions" where the IBAction was created, connected the IBAction to a button on the IB. Get this error: *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[NSCFString test]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x4d2ef40'

Comment: Is the name of the class called "Actions"?  And where did you change the name of the class?  Did you change it in Interface Builder under the section called "Custom Class"?

Comment: Yeap and yeap. Are you sure isn't anything else I should do? Maybe an appdelegate, idk.

Comment: Shouldn't need app delegate.  I am assuming that your method is called "test".  In that case, it seems to think that the object is not an "Actions" object, but an "NSCFString" object, which indicates that the class is not getting set correctly...

Answer (score 0):

If anyone is trying to do this on Swift 2, this is how:

```
import UIKit

class Actions: UIViewController {

    @IBAction func button1(sender: AnyObject) {

    }

}
```

Now the ViewController:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: Menu_Swipes {

}
```